The potential inside a hollow sphere with non-uniform surface potential
If there is a hollow sphere of radius $a$ whose surface potential is $V$ and if there is no change inside, the potential $\Phi(r\le a)=V$.
For the case the potential on the surface is non-uniformly set as
$$
\Phi(r=a,\theta)=
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
V&\text{if }\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]\\
0&\text{o.w.}
\end{array}\right.
$$
by solving the Laplace's equation, I managed to get the solution
$$
\Phi \left(r \le a, \theta\right) = \frac{V}{2} \left( 1 - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2\ell + 1}{\ell} P_{\ell + 1}(0) \left( \frac{r}{a} \right)^\ell P_\ell(\mu) \right)
$$
where $\mu=\cos\theta$ and $P_\ell(\mu)$ is a Legendre polynomial.
I then checked with computer results.
Setting $a = 1$, $V = 1$, and evaluating up to $\ell=1024$, I got the following results for the surface.
r = 1, θ = 0.0π, Φ = 0.9875
r = 1, θ = 0.125π, Φ = 0.9995
r = 1, θ = 0.25π, Φ = 0.9995
r = 1, θ = 0.375π, Φ = 0.9992
r = 1, θ = 0.5π, Φ = 0.5000
r = 1, θ = 0.625π, Φ = 0.0008
r = 1, θ = 0.75π, Φ = 0.0005
r = 1, θ = 0.875π, Φ = 0.0005
r = 1, θ = 1.0π, Φ = 0.0125

which is as expected.
However when $r$ is not at the surface, the results are
r = 0.5, θ = 0.0π, Φ = 0.8292
r = 0.5, θ = 0.125π, Φ = 0.8162
r = 0.5, θ = 0.25π, Φ = 0.7707
r = 0.5, θ = 0.375π, Φ = 0.6704
r = 0.5, θ = 0.5π, Φ = 0.5000
r = 0.5, θ = 0.625π, Φ = 0.3296
r = 0.5, θ = 0.75π, Φ = 0.2293
r = 0.5, θ = 0.875π, Φ = 0.1838
r = 0.5, θ = 1.0π, Φ = 0.1708

What I expected was the full upper hemisphere having $\Phi=V$ and the full lower hemisphere having $\Phi=0$ when $r\le a$. So now either my solution was incorrect or my prediction was incorrect.
Even when the surface has non-uniform potential, there is no charge inside the sphere, and the electric field inside would be zero. The field being zero implies constant potential. However the calculation results for $r=a/2$ shows that the potential is not constant in the hemispherical range. What did I miss?
